# Custom excel right click context menu gets overwritten by Quick Analysis defaults

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292899/vsto-document-level-individual-context-menu-in-excel-right-click-menu) to create a custom rightclick custom menu for an excel add-in with VSTO and display it under certain conditions (rightclick inside a range of an Excel named table).

My modified version of the code from the example works like a charm when I right click outside a named table range:

[image]

but it doesn't get displayed when you right click inside a named table range:

[image]

I suppose it has something to do with the Quick Analysis functionality interfering with my custom context menu overrides. Here is the code I'm using inside ThisAddin.cs:

```
 void Application_SheetBeforeRightClick(object worksheet, Excel.Range range, ref bool cancel)
{
  GetCellContextMenu().Reset(); // reset the cell context menu back to the default
  // If the selected range belongs within a named excel table we display the refresh menu item at the right click context menu.
  if (true) //range.IntersectsWithAnyExcelTable()) <-- this code works fine but I commented it out for the purpose of showing the problem (in this case the custom popup meny should appear ALWAYS):
  {
    const OfficeCore.MsoControlType menuItem = OfficeCore.MsoControlType.msoControlButton;
    var refreshMenuItem = (OfficeCore.CommandBarButton)GetCellContextMenu().Controls.Add(menuItem, missing, missing, 1, true);// where missing = global::System.Type.Missing;
        refreshMenuItem.Style = OfficeCore.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        refreshMenuItem.Caption = "Refresh My Data";
        refreshMenuItem.Click -= RefreshMenuItemClick;
        refreshMenuItem.Click += RefreshMenuItemClick;
      }
    }
```

and don't forget to subscribe the event when the add-in is started:

```
Application.SheetBeforeRightClick += Application_SheetBeforeRightClick;
```

How can I either:

1. Display my custom menu despite Quick Analysis kicking in.
2. Override quick analysis Refresh Button functionality (afaiu this is [impossible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469862%28v=office.14%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Excel uses a separate right-click menu for Tables.

I only speak VBA, so you will have to translate...

When right-clicking in a "normal" cell the `CommandBars("Cell")` menu is used.

When right-clicking in a Table the `CommandBars("List Range Popup")` menu is used.

Comment: After debugging it for a while we came to the same conclusion you posted above... the problem with that, was that there were 158 of those pop-up menus. You sir saved us a lot of time figuring out which was the right one to use for this case!

Comment: +1 for the answer. Removed the signature as per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed