# Revised Excel "cell" context menu doesn't work in table

Tags: excel, contextmenu, vba

I created a new item for the right click context menu in Excel.  It doesn't appear in my right click context menu when I right click on a cell in a table.  Otherwise it does appear.  The code that I used (copied from the web) is:

```
Sub AddItemToContextMenu()
  Dim cmdNew As CommandBarButton
  Set cmdNew = CommandBars("cell").Controls.Add

  With cmdNew
    .Caption = "Copy Occurence Across"
    .OnAction = "CopyOccurrence"
    .BeginGroup = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Is there something I can do to make my new item appear when clicking on a cell that's in a table?

Answer (score 5):

To add a control to the right-click context menu of a table item, you need to reference the "List Range Popup" context menu.

`CommandBars("List Range Popup").Controls.Add`

See the following post: [Custom excel right click context menu gets overwritten by Quick Analysis defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668109/custom-excel-right-click-context-menu-gets-overwritten-by-quick-analysis-default)